# Single word for "to bring within reach"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means "to bring within reach"/"make possible" for a technology or promising development.

For example

> Mobile phones _____ photography for the common person.

"Facilitate"/"make accessible" isn't quite right - I want to convey a step change, a paradigm shift.

In particular, I'm naming a business. I work in robotics. Robotics has long been touted as a way to  give people mobility, automate the mundane, and facilitate humans focusing on what matters to them.   My goal is to build tools for other companies to accelerate them and _____ the promises of robotics for humanity.

Comment: What do you mean by "accelerate" [these tools]? Come to that, what *are* "these tools"? Note that "promise" in such contexts would very rarely be pluralised, but I think ***implement / realize / actualize / ...** the  **potential** of robotics...* would probably be better anyway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really asking for a word with a specific meaning. It's effectively a request for writing advice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, what are you talking about? I'm literally asking for a single word to replace "to bring within reach". I included the startup context with the hope of having other people who are excited about language help me find the perfect word. If it is offensive to you for whatever reason, I can remove it.

Comment: If it's actually relevant,  "these tools" refers to common challenges faced in robotics e.g. precise localization.

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting "unleash" but it's so overused in tech marketing it's lost a lot of impact.

Comment: That there's a phrase "bring something within reach" suggests there's no single word that has that meaning.  The way it's often expressed is ***empower** the consumer with ....*  Or you could say *Mobile phones bring sophisticated photographic tools to the consumer* You got a problem with simple words?

Comment: Also, in your context it would be "the promise of robotics" not "the promises".

Comment: A phrase that often fills the slot you've left is **make real**.  make real the promise of robotics for humanity. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22make+real+the+promise%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=557208691&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&biw=1111&bih=606&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AB5stBjx0q5LwKXidUnqE5HUx5fymcLEzg%3A1692133596412&ei=3OjbZK3KGN-gptQPh9uCyAo&ved=0ahUKEwitqLTvyN-AAxVfkIkEHYetAKkQ4dUDCAk&oq=%22make+real+the+promise%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhcibWFrZSByZWFsIHRoZSBwcm9taXNlIkinN1DnBliYI3AAeACQAQCYAUOgAb4BqgEBM7gBDMgBAPgBAcICBRAhGKsCiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Comment: We see many questions asking for "a single word" to signify some complex notion. In this case there are reasonable answers, such as suggested by @FumbleFingers with "realise", for example. So the question is of an acceptable generic nature, is specific, and has at least one feasible answer. Therefore it should not be closed.

Comment: The word you want is _reach_ itself. It can be used to refer to ranges and possibilities, The example sentence with the phone works fine with _reaches_.

Comment: Is **deliver** too simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **unlock,** used in its broader metaphorical sense, might work. [Cambridge defines it as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/unlock)

> to make it possible for something to be used well, when previously it may not have been used enough

Answer (score 1):

If you **democratize** something, you make it accessible to everyone.

Examples :

> *Democratization of technology refers to the process by which access to technology rapidly continues to become more accessible to more
> people*.
> [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratization_of_technology)
>
> *Democratization of technology is about getting people involved in the creation of new technology and opening access to people who don’t have
> all the advanced skills and/or training. It’s often called “citizen
> access,” as it gives everyone the means to achieve technical or
> business expertise.*
> [source](https://www.walkme.com/glossary/it-democratization/)

Answer (score 1):

This is what first came to my mind: Realize

> [realize](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/realize) verb (ACHIEVE)
> to achieve something you were hoping for:
>
> *Lots of money, a luxury house, a fast car - Danny had realized all his
> ambitions by the age of 25.*